# Changing postion of legend box in plot.xts()

Tags: r, plot, legend, xts

I am trying to plot an xts object, but when I run my code, the legend is positioned on top of the title, how can i lower the postion of the legend box to have it right below the title (or at the top left but in my graph, and not above)? The full time period (index) goes from "2015-08-01" to "2017-01-31" and my y values range from 0 to 0.14.

my code:

```
plot(DTS_bar_xts,
 main = "Percentage of Observations of Status by Day.",
 xlab = "",
 ylab = "Percent",
 lwd = 1,
 lty = c(1, 2, 3),
 col = "black")
legend(x = "topleft",
   legend = c("Percent B", "Percent A", "Percent R"),
   lty = c(1, 2, 3),
   cex = .5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to move the legend easily: after creating plot type the following code: `locator(1)` then move with the mouse over your plot and click at the position where you want the top left corner of your legend box. This will return the x and y coordinates of that position in your console. Then use `legend(x = ..., y = ...)` with the two values for x and y and rerun with plot. Done!